# Ionic 2 application to print via Sunmi V1

Tags: printing, ionic2, cordova-plugins

For an ionic 2 app to print using Sunmi V1, added native plugin for printer by executing

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-printer
```

First I checked whether the printer is available by

```
checkPrinter() {
    this.printer.check().then(function () {
        alert("Printer available");
    }, function () {
        alert("Printer not available");
    });
}
```

It alerts "Printer available"

But the below method doesn't prompt any message

```
printData() {
    this.printer.isAvailable().then(function () {
        this.printer.print("Test Data").then(function () {
            alert("Printed");
        }, function () {
            alert("Printing error");
        });
    }, function () {
        alert('Unavailable');
    });
}
```

So I called Printer.print method directly as below

```
printData(){
    this.printer.print("Test Data").then(function () {
        alert("Printed");
    }, function () {
        alert("Printing Error");
    });
}
```

This method opens Print dialog to choose printer

[image]

If I select 'All Printers' from the dropdown to select printer instead of 'Save as PDF', then the search screen appears and keeps on searching...

[image]

Is some configuration missing or is it possible to interact with POS printers using cordova printer plugin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found a new plugin created by labibramadhan. Thanks labib

you can find the plugin here

https://github.com/labibramadhan/cordova-sunmi-inner-printer

First, install by typing ionic

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/labibramadhan/cordova-sunmi-inner-printer.git
```

Then, use it on your cordova javascript codes by calling:

```
window.sunmiInnerPrinter.printOriginalText("Hello World!")

window.sunmiInnerPrinter.[methods available on here]
```

https://github.com/labibramadhan/cordova-sunmi-inner-printer/blob/master/www/innerprinter.js

Thank you

Comment: For Ionic 3: In .ts file, add "declare let sunmiInnerPrinter: any;" before @Component and call the methods as "sunmiInnerPrinter.printOriginalText("Hello Printer");"

Comment: You saved my day, mate!!

Comment: Hey @Saravanan, I tried your methods, but no one is working. Please help me. :)

Do I need to add anything specific?
I already added the plugin in my ionic 3 app. And now trying to use it in app.component.ts.

Comment: Its necessary to import the plugin like import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular'; ?

Comment: @saberprashant Sorry, currently I am not working with this plugin.

Comment: Hi! Can you help me with my question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56327329/ionic3-printing-on-sumni-v1

Answer (score 1):

"Sunmi printer itself is not a network printer, web applications can not communicate directly with the printer, you need to accept data on the android applications" - From the documents available in their site. (I also contacted their support team but there was no proper reply)

As of now it doesn't support, so I am using github.com/shangmisunmi/SunmiPrinterDemo as example and developing the application in Android instead of ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation is not that easy:

http://docs.sunmi.com/htmls/index.html?lang=en##V1%20Docs%20&%20Resources

Comment: Thanks but I already checked all those documents even I contacted the support. "Sunmi printer itself is not a network printer, web applications can not communicate directly with the printer, you need to accept data on the android applications" => As of now it doesn't support, So I am using https://github.com/shangmisunmi/SunmiPrinterDemo as example and developing in Android.