# Printout issue with Sunmi inner printer plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have successfully generated printout using Sunmi V1 device. Thanks to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660026/9858789

But when printing the text using the functions available in the below link, I'm getting improper text printout. Though I'm printing the same text, it is jumbling the text when printing.

https://github.com/labibramadhan/cordova-sunmi-inner-printer/blob/master/www/innerprinter.js

The below is the code.

```html
sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\nABC Computers ','Calibri',36);
sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\nPlot No. 2, Road No 7, \nBanjara Hills,  \Hyderabad, 500003, TG \nPhone: +91 9876543210','Calibri',24);
sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\n**************************','Calibri',24);
sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\nName: Sachin\n','Calibri',32);
sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\nPhone: 9988776655\n','Calibri',32);
sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\nEmail: test@test.com\n','Calibri',32);
```

**This is the expected format:**

> ABC Computers
>
> Plot No. 2, Road No 7,
>
> Banjara Hills,
>
> Hyderabad, 500003, TG
>
> Name: Sachin
>
> Phone: 9988776655
>
> Email: test@test.com

The issue is in the first printout I'm getting one printout order

> ABC Computers
>
> Name: Sachin
>
> Phone: 9988776655
>
> Email: test@test.com
>
> Plot No. 2, Road No 7,
>
> Banjara Hills,
>
> Hyderabad, 500003, TG

In the other printout, I am getting the below printout.

> ABC Computers
>
> Phone: 9988776655
>
> Email: test@test.com
>
> Plot No. 2, Road No 7,
>
> Banjara Hills,
>
> Hyderabad, 500003, TG
>
> Name: Sachin

Advice me, where I am doing wrong?

Comment: It got resolved. Removed the below line in ThreadPoolManager.java.  int num = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 20;

Comment: Do you know how to change the font size with bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because it is synchronous. simply wait for each promise to resolve before going on to the next. this should work.

```
sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\nABC Computers ','Calibri',36).then((f: any) => {
    sunmiInnerPrinter.printTextWithFont('\nPlot No. 2, Road No 7, \nBanjara Hills,  \Hyderabad, 500003, TG \nPhone: +91 9876543210','Calibri',24).then( 
        ...etc.
    )
})
```